# Recursive function in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion

I get an error when I write this recursive function in Angular 2 (Typescript):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.countdown(6)
}

countdown(time) {
    this.timeLeft = time - 1
    console.log(this.timeLeft)
    setInterval(function() {
      this.countdown(this.timeLeft)
    }, 1000)
 }
```

*timeLeft* is declared as a class property.

Here is the error I get:

```
EXCEPTION: this.countdown is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440

Comment: You definitely do not want to start a new *interval* on every recursive call. Use `setTimeout` instead. And don't forget the `if (this.timeLeft > 0)` condition.